# Should I be throwing different exception types?

Tags: php, exception, phpunit

When throwing exceptions on purpose, I have always just used PHP's basic Exception class, just with a different message, e.g.:

```
<?php
if($a < $b){
  throw new Exception('a is smaller than b');
}elseif($a > $b){
  throw new Exception('a is larger than b');
}
```

However, recently I have noticed that some people throw different classes of exception, e.g.:

```
<?php
if($a < $b){
  throw new aIsSmallerThanBException();
}elseif($a > $b){
  throw new aIsLargerThanBException();
}
```

What are the advantages/disadvantages of these two methods? Should I be doing it in the second style? I have noticed that in unit testing with PHPUnit you can tell it that you are expecting a certain class of exception using setExpectedException(). Does this mean that the second method is better in terms of making code testable?

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use pseudo-tags in titles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those different exceptions can make the flow easier, because you are allowed to catch several types of exceptions at once. Take a look at this:

```
function mustBeEqual($a, $b){
  if($a < $b){
    throw new aIsSmallerThanBException()('a is smaller than b');
  }elseif($a > $b){
    throw new aIsLargerThanBException()('a is larger than b');
  } else {
    //Everything is ok, proceed.
  }
}

try {
  mustBeEqual(3, 4);
} catch (isLargerThanBException $e){
  echo "A is greater than B" ;
} catch (isSmallerThanBException $e){
  echo "A is smaller than B" ;
} catch (Exception e){
  echo "Default exception was triggered: " . $e->getMessage() ;
}
```

First you expect some specific exceptions to catch, then you use the default exception just to be sure you catch it. Every specific exception is a derived class of `Exception` and inherit such methods as `getCode` and `getMessage`.

I can also give you an example how it works:

1. Call a function in a try-catch block. Function throws an exception.
2. Try to catch a `ConnectionTimeoutException`. The exception is not of this type. Move to the next `catch`.
3. Try to catch an `AccessForbiddenException`. The exception is of this type. Notify user about the problem.
4. We dont move to the next catch, because the exception is caught already. This is it.

Answer (score 2):

It's a matter of selectivity. Different Exception classes can be handled by different `catch` clauses, and so enable you to run specific code depending on what caused the exception. This can be particularly important when you have multiple nested levels of `try-catch` blocks.

Another thing is code readability and easier debugging. [`OutOfBoundsException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.outofboundsexception.php) tells the debugging person something, that plain `Exception` doesn't. SPL defines a bunch of useful [exception classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php) that cover most common issues. Using these SPL Exceptions you clearly communicate why an exception was thrown. The other person just needs to look up an appropriate `php.net` page.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of making code testable, you can use the second one. The advantage is you can use that exception in any script once that exception is exist. If the first one, you should declare new exception like this `throw new Exception('....');` each time you want to use exception.